# Magento 2 Configurable product with multiple color swatches

Tags: magento2, swatches

I'm creating a configurable product, each simple product has multiple colors, how can I create multiple swatches for each simple product of its configurable one?

Answer (score 0):

go to STORES -> Attributes -> Product. add a new attribute, after that add a new product and Select the attribute you added for that product.

Comment: But I need to create swatches/variations with multiple colors!

Comment: https://prnt.sc/pb1rbm check it.

Comment: Maybe I was not that clear, I need to create a configurable product which has variations/swatches that have multiple color, each variation has more than one color.... Each simple product which is a variation of the configurable has more than one color.....